# C# WPF - large custom mouse cursor sizes

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

I am using code I found to render text as my cursor

[Here's the website with the code](https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/12/18/714-setting-the-cursor-to-render-some-text-while-dragging/)

I copied the code below just in case:

```
public class CursorHelper
{
    private static class NativeMethods
    {
        public struct IconInfo
        {
            public bool fIcon;
            public int xHotspot;
            public int yHotspot;
            public IntPtr hbmMask;
            public IntPtr hbmColor;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern SafeIconHandle CreateIconIndirect(ref IconInfo icon);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetIconInfo(IntPtr hIcon, ref IconInfo pIconInfo);
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
    private class SafeIconHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        public SafeIconHandle()
            : base(true)
        {
        }

        override protected bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return NativeMethods.DestroyIcon(handle);
        }
    }

    private static Cursor InternalCreateCursor(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp)
    {
        var iconInfo = new NativeMethods.IconInfo();
        NativeMethods.GetIconInfo(bmp.GetHicon(), ref iconInfo);

        iconInfo.xHotspot = 0;
        iconInfo.yHotspot = 0;
        iconInfo.fIcon = false;

        SafeIconHandle cursorHandle = NativeMethods.CreateIconIndirect(ref iconInfo);
        return CursorInteropHelper.Create(cursorHandle);
    }

    public static Cursor CreateCursor(string cursorText)
    {
        // Text to render
        FormattedText fmtText = new FormattedText(cursorText,
                new CultureInfo("en-us"),
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface(new FontFamily("Arial"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, new FontStretch()),
                12.0,  // FontSize
                Brushes.Black);

        // The Visual to use as the source of the RenderTargetBitmap.
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
        drawingContext.DrawText(fmtText, new Point());
        drawingContext.Close();

        // The BitmapSource that is rendered with a Visual.
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)drawingVisual.ContentBounds.Width,
            (int)drawingVisual.ContentBounds.Height,
            96,   // dpiX
            96,   // dpiY
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        rtb.Render(drawingVisual);

        // Encoding the RenderBitmapTarget into a bitmap (as PNG)
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms))
            {
                return InternalCreateCursor(bmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is when the size is too large, the cursor fails to render. From what I've seen, once a dimension of the text exceeds 96, this will happen.

Is this a limitation of the size of a cursor? Is there any way to bypass this? I know I could make a canvas and render an image and have it follow my mouse position or something like that, but I'm curious of an actual solution using the WPF Cursor class.

Comment: Try the solution from the link. I bet you can combine that with your Text as Cursor stuff

Comment: @TobiasTheel - thanks, but isn't that solution for Windows Forms Cursors? I'm using the WPF ones. And also, I want to override the cursor for my application, not the entire computer, so I don't think I should be using `SetSystemCursor`